# Is 'Ladies center, men sashay, left allemande.' a complete and grammatical sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, imperative-sentences

Source: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=B2NRV_X_F8WL8Qe-xpvwDg#q=sashay+meaning

> Ladies center, men sashay, left allemande.
>
> Roll away with a half sashay, then face your original partner.

These are two separate sentences.

They don't seem like complete sentences to me because they seem to be lacking verbs, e.g. 'Ladies center'.

Comment: Why do you ask? Would you explain a bit more why you think it might not be grammatical? Also there are two sentences here.

Comment: Yes, two sentences.They seem to lacking verbs, eg ladies at center

Comment: I went ahead and added that information to your answer and retracted my close vote. We can write better answers if we understand why you are confused, so it really helps to add some explanation. There is some advice in [this thread](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/) on [meta] for writing detailed questions.

Comment: "Hi!" -- Did I just make a grammatical mistake?

Comment: The way I understand "Ladies center" is "Ladies, move to the center". It's not unusual when directing people. You could also say "Sprites stage left. Ariel center." if you were choreographing or directing a play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Out!* is a grammatical and complete sentence.

Both the verb and subject are implied or ellided (depending on how one analyzes the sentence).

From context, it is clear who the subject is. In commands, it is often the person or persons that you are speaking to (the addressee or addressees) so that would be *you* (singular or plural). If it is you plural, you can also address them as 'you' (meaning *you plural*),  'you all' or 'everybody' or 'everyone'.

So now we have

> You, out!

or

> You all, out!

or

> Everybody, out!

The verb is implied, but from context we know that the speaker wants his addressee(s) to leave the room or area, so the implied verb is anything that indicates this. And since this is a command, the verb is in the [imperative](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/imperative/menu.php):

> You, get/go out!

or

> You all, get/go out!

or

> Everybody, get/go out!

The utterances you ask about can be analyzed as complete sentences, in the same way.

> Ladies center, men sashay, left allemande

can be seen as a version of

> (You)  ladies (go/move to the) center, (you)  men sashay, (you all, or everybody) (do a) left [allemande](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/allemande).

with *[sashay](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sashay)* used as a verb in the imperative, just as *go/move* and *do* are.

The other one lacks only an explicit subject, which can be supplied by either *everybody*/*everyone* or *you all* before *roll away*. For example

> Everybody, roll away with a half sashay, then face your original partner.

*Roll away* is a verb. *Face* is a verb. *Sashay* is a noun here.

Answer (score -2):

Neither of the sentences in your example is grammatically correct if you are judging them by normal English usage. The fact that they are not grammatically correct in normal usage doesn't mean that they are incorrect in other usages, however. The example sentences appear to be a set instructions by a [dance caller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_(dancing)#The_modern_Western_square_dance_caller), and that usage of English is less concerned with grammatical correctness and more with timing and getting the dancers to follow precise dance moves.

Comment: I would agree with this answer :) +1

Comment: Why is this usage "less concerned with grammatical correctness"? How is this usage not "normal English usage"?

Comment: Why do you think instructions are not grammatical? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/commands-and-instructions